# How to map exceptions in spring webflux controllers?

Tags: java, exception, spring-webflux

We use controllers in our spring webflux project, e.g.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("fail")
    public Mono<String> getFailure() {
        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error"));
    }
}
```

Now, when one opens the http://localhost:8080/fail URL in a browser, they would see the "Whitelabel Error Page" coming from spring. Question: how to map `RuntimeException` to a custom HTTP response?

These options have no effect on the response:

1. `@ExceptionHandler` in the controller

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public Mono<ServerResponse> onException(Exception e) {
    return ServerResponse
        .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .body("error response", String.class);
}
```

2. `@RestControllerAdvice` annotated class

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice
{
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public Mono<String> exceptions(Throwable e)
    {
        return Mono.just("error response");
    }
}
```

3. `ResponseStatusException` instance

```
@GetMapping("fail")
public Mono<String> getFailure() {
    return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("error"))
        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error happened")))
        .map(obj -> (String) obj);  // casting
}
```

How to map exceptions to custom HTTP responses in spring webflux when using controllers? Why don't the above approaches work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are returning `Producers`. An exception is a terminal event.

If you look in the examples provided in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-controller-exceptions) you can see that they are not returning `Mono<ServerResponse>` but a plain `ResponseEntity<T>`.

Exception handler in a Controller.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("fail")
    public Mono<String> getFailure() {
        // return Mono.just("hello world");
        return Mono.error(new NullPointerException("error"));
    }

    // Here i build a response entity
    @ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> onException(NullPointerException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

Or here in the controller advice i just return a plain `String`.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {

    // I can return a response entity or for instance just a plain string
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String exceptions(Throwable e) {
        return "Foobar";
    }
}
```